# Why is my Discord bot not loading any of the commands stored in the cogs?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have my cogs stored in the folder modules, with each cog within its own subfolder of modules. The code is below. Modules and my main.py file(the file the code below is in) are both in the same folder, so I shouldn't need the full path for modules. All of the cogs are named cog.py so that shouldnt be the issue either.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import discord
import os
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands

dotenv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'temp.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)
 


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="#",intents =discord.Intents.all()) 

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

for folder in os.listdir("modules"):
  if os.path.exists(os.path.join('modules', folder, 'cog.py')):
    client.load_extension(f"modules.{folder}.cog")

token = os.getenv('TOKEN')
if token is not None:
    client.run(token)
else:
    print("Error: TOKEN environment variable is not set")
```

I've tried pasting in the full file path for modules and it didnt work. I was expecting it to recognize the cogs and the commands within them, but whenever I try calling one of the commands, I get "ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ping" is not found" (the command I tried calling is just called ping)

Answer (score 0):

The `client.load_extension` is a coroutine, meaning you have to `await` it.

```py
await client.load_extension('...')
```

However, you cannot `await` in the global scope, `discord.py` introduced a new function to help us load extensions called `Bot.setup_hook`, here's a little snippet:

```py
async def setup_hook():
    for folder in os.listdir("modules"):
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join('modules', folder, 'cog.py')):
            await client.load_extension(f"modules.{folder}.cog")


client.setup_hook = setup_hook
```